# Transaction status failed '0x0'

Tags: ethereum, web3js, quorum

I try to send rawTransactions to Quorum blockchain, the same method that I used for the Ethereum Ropsten.
The issue was I got transaction status returned as '0x0', which is transaction failed according to the online documents.
I would like to know that is that anyways I can get the details of the failing error message from the Quorum blockchain?

The only different is I changed the gasPrice to '0x0' for the Quorum transactions.
Please advise.